# C++ SMTP client no response after connecting to server

Tags: c++, smtp, winsock

I am trying to create a SMTP client to send emails, but I can't make it connect to smtp.gmail.com.
The connect itself doesn't seem to fail, but recv blocks without giving any welcome message. Works as expected when I use Telnet.

```
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    iResult = getaddrinfo("smtp.gmail.com", "465", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

    std::cout << recvbuf << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], or at the very least the entire function.

Comment: How do you expect to get a welcome message that's been encrypted with TLS, since you're connecting to the SMTP-over-TLS port 465, without the benefit of using any TLS library, from the looks of it, in the shown code? Can you explain how you allegedly got telnet, which does not support any encryption whatsoever, as far as I know, to validate the server's SSL certificate, then decrypt the encrypted traffic, after connecting to port 465?

Comment: Port 25 works... I didn't expect to be able to send mail using 465 port before getting TLS, but I did somewhat expect a welcome message. Code that I had before didn't work with any port, hence the post, but after cleaning it up a bit for posting and changing some stuff it seems to work. And Telnet gives no reply with port 465 either, most likely used port 25 then.

Comment: Port 465 uses TLS. The connecting client is expected to send the first encrypted packet, the "ClientHello" packet. That's why you get bupkis. You will find more information by doing a Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 465 uses *implicit* TLS, which requires the client to negotiate a TLS session immediately upon connecting, before it can then read the server's (encrypted) welcome message. You are not getting anything because the server is not sending anything yet. It is waiting for you to send a TLS handshake, which you are not doing.

There is also the concept of *explicit* TLS, on port 25 and 587, where the client has to read the (unencrypted) welcome message first and then send a `STARTTLS` command before negotiating a TLS session.